# Is there a way to use compound fields for 'Where not exists'

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists, not-exists

I'm trying to insert rows from table paycom to table users and i only want to insert them if the unique UserName does not already exist. The UserName is generated via the first letter of their first name and last name from the paycom table. I've tried various methods but I'm having trouble comparing Username from the user table with a combination of other fields from the paycom table. I've tried various methods but it tells me that the multipart method can't be found or the field doesn't exist.
Any idea?
Thanks

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[tblUser] (
       [FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[Email]
      ,[Location]
      ,[Active]
      ,[Position]
      ,[UserName]
      )
SELECT [Firstname]
      ,[Lastname]
      ,[WorkEmail]
      ,[Department]
      ,1
      ,[JobTitleCode]
      ,LEFT(FirstName,1) + LastName + pin as t1
FROM Paycom
WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select UserName,UserId From [test].[dbo].[tblUser] WHERE tblUser.UserName =[test].[dbo].[tblUser].[Paycom].t1)
and HireDate >= GETDATE();
```

Comment: You can't use aliases from the Select clause in the where clause.

Comment: so what should I do? It doesn't seem to let me compound the two fields I want as a comparison in the where clause.

Comment: repeat the `LEFT(FirstName,1) + LastName` in the where clause as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make your WHERE clause like this.

```
WHERE NOT (
   LEFT(paycom.FirstName,1) = LEFT([test].[dbo].[tblUser].[firstname],1)
        AND  paycom.lastname = [test].[dbo].[tblUser].[lastname]
    )
        and HireDate >= GETDATE();
```

Note this may not be the most efficient way to handle this, but it should get you started.

Comment: thanks for the response. 
Unfortunately
```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    Select 1 FROM Paycom 
    WHERE LEFT(paycom.FirstName,1) = LEFT([test].[dbo].[tblUser].[FirstName],1)
```
Gives me the error 
```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
The multi-part identifier "test.dbo.tblUser.FirstName" could not be bound.
```
I'm not incredibly familiar with SQL but it looks like the error is telling me I have to define the table with a FROM statement, but how would I use multiple FROM statements?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I updated the Paycom table to include a new column that i used to make the username column that i wanted to import to the user table.
From there i was able to simplify the 'where not exists' argument and have the insert run correctly. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I updated the Paycom table to include a new column that i used to make the username column that i wanted to import to the user table. From there i was able to simplify the 'where not exists' argument and have the insert run correctly. Thanks